# Cannot connect to the ip provided by the OWASP BWA

Tags: virtualbox, owasp

I have installed **owasp bwa** in virtual box. And when I run the vm I got an IP address to connect to.But, when I'm trying to access it using **http://ip-address**, it failed to connect. And I'm not able to ping it from my host network.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VM Network settings and and change it to Bridge Adapter.